# Using algebraic data types for F# to solve algebra problems

Tags: f#, algebra, algebraic-data-types

How do algebraic data types in f# work? I want to see a basic sample program to explain it but can't seem to find any.

For example, maybe a code that does the quadratic formula or solutions to finding the areas of shapes.

Comment: http://tomasp.net/blog/types-and-math.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The adjective `algebraic` in `algebraic data types` does not refer to a type used to solve an algebra problem, e.g.

```
x + y = 3  or 5 * y = 10
```

the adjective `algebraic` refers to the way types are constructed/declared using the `algebraic` operators of multiplication (`*`) and addition (`+`). In particular algebraic types can be [product types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type) (`*`) which are tuples, e.g.

```
type Variable = string * int
```

and [sum types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), which use the or character (`|`) instead of the plus character (`+`) which are discriminated unions, e.g.

```
type Term =
    | Var of Variable
    | Const of Constant
    | App of Constant * Term list
```

Once one understands that and shifts their thinking the Wikipedia article on [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) should make sense and this will explain why you are not finding what you seek, e.g. articles that explain how to solve algebra problems using algebraic data types.

In essence new types are built up from [primitive data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) such as `int`, `char`, `string`, etc. and the algebraic operators of `product` and `summation` but more importantly, algebraic data types are based on [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) and being a [formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) bring with it all the benefits of a formal system.

Also of note is the difference in the operators for declaring the tuple type and the operators used for creating a tuple value e.g.

```
type Variable = string * int    type
("x",0)                         value
```

notice the `*` operator for the type and the `,` operator for the value.

Also

```
type Term =                           type
  | Var of Variable
  | Const of Constant
  | App of Constant * Term list  

Var("x",0)                            value
Const("1")                            value
App("add",[Const("1"),Var("x",0)])    value
```

notice that each `possible option` has to have a `case identifier` when used with a value.

As you learn more about ADTs you will run into [generalized algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type) but sadly F# does not have them but have been [requested](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5664643-add-support-for-gadts).

Mark Seemann provided a link to [Power of mathematics - Reasoning about functional types](http://tomasp.net/blog/types-and-math.aspx/) by Tomas Petricek. Tomas then has a dead link `fairly readable introduction` but here it is or something similar: [What the Heck are Algebraic Data Types? ( for Programmers )](http://merrigrove.blogspot.com/2011/12/another-introduction-to-algebraic-data.html) or the series which I prefer by Chris Taylor which uses Haskell, but the ideas do translate to F#:

[The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types, Part 1](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/)
[The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types, Part 2](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/11/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-part-ii/)
[The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types, Part 3](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/13/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-part-iii/)

Comment: So basically, F# is just a functional programming language similar to Pyret?

Comment: This is the first I have heard of [Pyret](https://www.pyret.org/), but after a quick read of the intro paragraph I would agree that they are both functional languages of the [ML family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) but I could not find ADT for Pyret, and what little I read about the type system for Pyret, I would not say that translating from one into the other would be easy because of how different the type systems are.

Comment: While you have already asked the question and have an answer, this comment leads me to believe that you were looking for help with Pyret but took Pyret to be close to F# and went from there. Asking a new question about the differences between the type systems of Pyret and F# would be interesting but I don't know anyone, including myself, who could answer.

Comment: No, not really. We were discussing Pyret in our Programming Languages class and had to look for languages and explain what's "unique" about them through sample programs.

Comment: I looked at some more code of Pyret and while I still do not see any direct mention of ADT I do see the elements that make up ADT there, so I will back away from my earlier comment of `not say that translating from one into the other would be easy`. I am use to more formal definitions of languages and searching on certain keywords. As this language is still under development I had to step back to a more basic means to look at this language.

Comment: With regards to `explain what's "unique" about them through sample programs` I would direct you to [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Tasks). Pick a task and then look at all of the different ways to implement the task in a different language.

Comment: True. Actually pyret uses sum types but I didn't encounter product types just yet. And I can't choose rosetta because sadly, I was forcibly assigned to F#.

Comment: Rosetta is not a programming language but a site that shows how task are solved in many different languages. Take a look and I think it will be of great benefit to you for your assignment. Not all task at Rosetta are done in F#, but many are.

Comment: For Pyret product type, (tuple), look at this example `link(first, rest)` on [home page](https://www.pyret.org/). `(first,rest)` is a tuple. In F# a tuple `value` is defined using the `,` operator but a tuple `type` definition is defined using the `*` operator. Also `node(value, left :: BinTree, right :: BinTree)` is a tuple with three types identified by the variable names of `value`, `left`, and `right`. The odd think here between F# and Pyret is that F# uses `:` between variable and type and Pyret uses `::`. But F# uses `::` for concatenation.

Comment: `I was forcibly assigned to F#.` if I had F# assigned to me I would be happy; are you not happy with F#? I ask because if you have that problem then so do others and while we who use F# do not claim it to be a perfect language, we typically do find it to be a practical and useful language. There are cracks and faults but the pluses outweigh the negatives more often than not.